# MongoDB error 'input to $filter must be an array not object'

Tags: mongodb

I have a document structure like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "_meta" : {
        "information" : "some info",
        "symbol" : "someSymbol",
    },
    "array" : [
        {
            "date" : "2021-01-29",
            "value" : "719.4600"
        },
        {
            "date" : "2019-09-30",
            "value" : "224.0800"
        },
        {
            "date" : "2017-09-29",
            "value" : "356.1200",
        },
        ...

}
```

I run JSON query in mongodb:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "array": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$array",
          "as": "a",
          "cond": {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$lte": [
                  "$$a.date",
                  "2020"
                ]
              },
              {
                "$gte": [
                  "$$a.date",
                  "2016"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This worked fine when I made a similar request in other documents, but in this case I get the following error: `input to $filter must be an array not object`

Has anyone encountered this before? What could be the problem?

Comment: do a find to see if in all collection `array` field is always an array, seems that in some document its document not array

Answer (score 0):

The error message states exactly what the problem is.

There might be a document in your collection where `array` key is object type instead of `array` and `$filter` operator only accepts array as its input parameter.

I suggest you to add a `$match` stage and check for `array` object type or use the `$cond` stage and convert object into array if you want to include those documents too in your aggregation result.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "array": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$eq": [
                  {
                    "$type": "$array"
                  },
                  "array"
                ]
              },
              "then": "$array",
              "else": [
                "$array"
              ],
              
            }
          },
          "as": "a",
          "cond": {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$lte": [
                  "$$a.date",
                  "2020"
                ]
              },
              {
                "$gte": [
                  "$$a.date",
                  "2016"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/blJ1dZjpwqs)

Comment: I tried your solution, but for some reason an empty array is returned... [Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9IJioNe6bY6) I wrote a similar query, which, it seems to me, is no different from the one in my question. I still can't figure out what the difference is between them

Comment: @sorohimm, were you able to pinpoint the exact document you are facing trouble with? The difference from my query to yours is that I have added a `$cond` operator as input to `$filter` operator. This will help in converting `array` key values which have `object` as value type.